# RelativeLayout over another RelativeLayout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a viewpager implemented on my app. In all my fragments I have circlepageindicator, header and footer. My main xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.app"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Header aligned to top -->

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        app:radius="4dp"
        app:fillColor="#00CCFF"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dip" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
<include layout="@layout/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_centerInParent = "true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

My footer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app_rotate" />
```

The output of the code is:

[image]

As you can see, the header part is below the background of the fragment but the footer is not. I want to see my header like the footer is. As you can see I have provided all the xml attributes to header like footer but why the output is not same? I hope I get some help from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-order of elements is a "last one on top" model.

Move this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/header" />
```

To come after the main body:

```
</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Comment: @bShah - cool. Now show me some love and give me the green check. :)

Comment: I am in hurry to do that but it says to wait for couple of minutes to accept :)